# How do I keep HTML aspect ratio when browser is zoomed

Tags: html, css, viewport

I'm using a lot of divs with fixed aspect ratios in my website. I use the padding-top trick like this:-

A page with a centered 1400px container, containing a 1:1 aspect ratio div.

```
<div style="max-width:1400px;margin:auto 0;">
    <div style="width:100%;padding-top:100%;"></div>
</div>
```

But when customers zoom in or out of the website, the aspect ratio stretches and shrinks. It seems to be using the width of the browser not the container.

Any suggestions on how to fix this behaviour? It happens in all browsers I tested.

Note: Could be viewport related, not sure.

Just in case, viewport is:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

Comment: have you tried giving the container div a position:relative ?

Comment: Just looked, turns out it already is.